# Getting response back from using redux-thunk and AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, jwt, axios, redux-thunk, asyncstorage

I am using react-native, redux-thunk, jwt and AsyncStorage to authenticate and locate user in this project. It seems that the request goes to backend from the axios, but I do not see the response back ('in axios' and '?' are not displayed) in the chrome console and I have no idea what possibly goes wrong in my code.

in my actions/userAuth.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export function updateUserLoc(username, lat, lng) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(function(token) {
      console.log('out');
      axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/:${username}/location`, {location: [lat, lng], token})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('in axios');
        // console.log('update user location', response);
        dispatch({
          type: USER_LOC_UPDATE
        });
        console.log('?');
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log('user location err', err); });
    })
    .catch(err => { console.log('Async Storage err', err)});
  }
}
```

has anyone had this kind of problem before or does anybody know what the problem is in this code and how to debug it?

will appreciate any kind of advice or answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `AsyncStorage.getItem` returns a Promise.  According to the docs, `getItem` takes an optional second param that is your callback function.  Alternatively you can use `async/await` if you have ES7 support.